# A variant of the method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have the following equation

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k +  Ae^x = \sum_{k=0}^n b_k  x^k + B e^x $$

Well, we know that if the exponentials were not present on the equation, then $a_k = b_k $ all $k$. However, in this situation, $\mathbf{can}$ we conclude as well that $A = B$? If so, how can we generalize this method?

Comment: Hint: $(A-B)e^x$ grows to infinity faster than any polynomial, unless...

Comment: Alternative hint: Take the derivative of both sides.

Comment: So, basically, if we take the derivative n times, we end up with $A = B$, and then we can come back to our original equation and it reduces to the case $\sum a_k x^k = \sum b_k x^k $ which we know how to solve. Correct?

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but which one is your unknown? Suppose that you want to find $a_k$ for $x=0$, then you have $a_0+A=b_0+B$